# Read from .env file and set as bash variables

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

How can I read an .env file and set the variables as bash variables? Currently, I'm able to read it and export them as environment variables.

If the file contains the variables:

```bsh
DB_NAME=mydb
DB_PASSWORD=abcd1234
```

Then, `DB_NAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` will be bash variables and they will contain the respective values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If a text file is formatted as

```
DB_NAME=mydb
DB_PASSWORD=abcd1234
```

then these variables can be set in the current bash shell simply by sourcing the file as:

```
source my_custom.env
```

Comment: For answers to almost all your Bash qquestions, find and study the Bash guides at www.tldp.org

Comment: this WON'T work for any .env variable that contains certain characters. e.g. `PASSWORD=abcd;1234` is a valid .env file but would not work in bash with `source` (it'd read just 'abcd')

Comment: @istepaniuk There is also something like "quoting" in bash to handle characters with a special meaning.

Comment: @vanadium That's true when the .env file is a bash/shell compatible file (such as PHP DotEnv and others). But not true for many other common .env implementations, such as docker's envfiles, where there is no expansion and quoting would result in the actual quotes being included in the value. The later case is common enough that maybe a "depends on your .env file standard" clarification could improve this answer.

Comment: @istepaniuk A more broad answer may be suited for another Stackexchange site, but not for this site dedicated to Ubuntu

Answer (score 3):

An improved approach that ignores comments is

```
export $(grep -v '^#' my_custom.env | xargs)
```

Comment: It's not necessarily always an improvement to invert match and ignore comments.

Comment: A better answer would explain that grep -v does an inverse match on the regex, which matches # at start of line, ... What's xargs doing here? Handling spaces/non-ASCII??

Comment: This approach forks lots, grep $() and the |xargs all have processes.
`source` is a bash builtin , i.e. its does not fork at all